# Setting value equal to itself

Tags: c, gcc, standards, c99, undefined-behavior

I don't know where to search for this (probably the standard but still don't know what to search for), so I will ask this here.

If in some execution `array[i2]` will be set to `array[i]` where `i2` happens to be equal to `i`, then is this defined behavior?

I'm using *C99* (with *gcc 4.8.1*), looking at the assembly with `gcc -S`, I don't see anything suspicious.

Comment: The compiler may even optimize that out.

Comment: It won't as it depends on runtime execution. That's the reason I noted "in some execution". It's actually more like array[idx] = array[i], where idx happens to be equal to i.

Comment: @Silverrocker: Specify what kind of dependency you mean.

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify the situation.

Comment: This may be the same as "int i, j; j = i". Reading of i is undefined, so you could say the whole statement is undefined. Similarly for an array element which hasn't been previously assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If variable `i` has valid value then assignment

```
i = i;
```

has perfectly defined behavior. This is equivalent to your question, as stated.

If there's something more tricky in your situation, you have to provide more details about it.

Comment: That is all there is so your answer applies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely defined behaviour. The right-hand-side of an assignment is calculated first, then assigned to the left-hand-side. Note that the left-hand-side must resolve to an lvalue.

Comment: Note that this is actually the same as settings a variable to be equal to itself. Does that change the situation?

Answer (score 1):

```
foo() {
  int i, j, a[5], b[5];
  i = i; // undefined because reading i is UB
  j = i; // undefined because reading i is UB
  a[i] = a[i]; // undefined because reading i is UB
  a[3] = a[3]; // undefined because reading a[3] is UB
  b[3] = a[3]; // undefined because reading a[3] is UB
}
```

Comment: If the variables are initialized, then it becomes defined, correct?

Comment: ok, I thought this might be sequence point related, but this seems not to be the case. Thanks.